# Increment field in MySql if duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that keeps track of IP addresses with 3 fields -- ID, IP, TOTAL.

If I'm inserting a duplicate IP value, I'd like to just increment the TOTAL field by 1.

How should I do this?

Comment: post the sample INPUT data and OutPut data

Comment: just create a trigger on the table

Comment: INSERT INTO visitors (IP) VALUES ($ip);

I'm doing this as part of PHP code. The SQL statement is working but it's creating a new row on every insert, even when the IP is already in the table. I'm trying to count the # of visits per IP address so I want the TOTAL field to increment by 1 on every INSERT attempt where the IP already exists in the table.

Comment: I am trying to create a trigger but am having trouble crafting the statement.

Comment: Oh, it is found that trigger cannot update the record when insert on the same table, so only create a stored procedure can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this if your IP is UNIQUE

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, ip, total) VALUES (1, xxx.xxx.x.x, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = total+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean counting the total ? then add 1 if `IP` is already existing ?

```
    DECLARE @Total INT = (SELECT COUNT(Total) From TableName)

    IF EXIST (SELECT IP From TableName)
       BEGIN
          SET @Total = @Total + 1
       END

    INSERT INTO...
```

Answer (score 0):

**sp_visitors.sql**

```
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_visitors (IN in_ip varchar(50))
begin
    declare var_total int;
    set var_total = (select total from ip_table where ip = in_ip);
    if (var_total is null) then
        insert into ip_table (ip, total) values (in_ip, 1);
    else
        update ip_table set total = total + 1 where ip = in_ip;
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

**grant privilege**

```
grant all on db.* to 'user'@'localhost';
```

**call**

```
call sp_visitors('192.168.168.1');
```